# Scheduling: execute tasks only one time in spring boot

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks

Im trying to manage scheduled tasks using spring boot. I want to execute my job **only one time at a particular date** ( specified by the user ). User can add dates for execution as much as he wants.Here is my Job :

```
@Component
public class JobScheduler{

    @Autowired
    ServiceLayer service;

    @PostConstruct
    public void executeJob(){
        try {
            service.execute();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

And here is the execute method :

```
private TaskScheduler scheduler;

Runnable exampleRunnable = new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("do something ...");
    }
};

@Override
    @Async
    public void execute() throws Exception {
        try {

            List<Date> myListOfDates = getExecutionTime();  // call dao to get dates insered by the user

            ScheduledExecutorService localExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
            scheduler = new ConcurrentTaskScheduler(localExecutor);
            for(Date d : myListOfDates ){
            scheduler.schedule(exampleRunnable, d);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Issue 1 : Im using PostConstruct annotation. Thus, when executeJob method is called, there is no dates in the List 'myListOfDates'.

Issue 2 : Supposing that myListOfDates contains dates, how can i get the latest dates in case user entered another one?

Issue 3 : If i use @Scheduled(initailDelay=10000, fixedRate=20000) instead of @PostConstruct annotation, it will resolve the first issue, but it will execute my job every 20s for instance.

Any clue ?

Comment: I think you had better to use 3rd-party library for scheduling, such as quartz. Those are well-tested, production ready, and easily configurable.

Comment: I think quartz includes two types of triggers :                                SimpleTrigger – Allows to set start time, end time, repeat interval.
CronTrigger – Allows Unix cron expression to specify the dates and times to run your job.  And none of them fit my issue. Am I wrong ?

Comment: `SimpleTrigger should meet your scheduling needs if you need to have a job execute exactly once at a specific moment in time, or at a specific moment in time followed by repeats at a specific interval ... The repeat count can be zero, ...` http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-05.html Does it fit your needs?

Comment: SimpleTrigger trigger = (SimpleTrigger) newTrigger() .withIdentity("trigger1", "group1") 
.startAt(myStartTime) // some Date 
.forJob("job1", "group1") // identify job with name, group strings 
.build(); 

With this, i can specify only one date. But i have a list of dates and this list can be refreshed at any time by the user..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can infer from your question is, you are asking how to make jobs triggered based on some list of date when spring started.

**First**, instead of using `@PostConstruct` in a bean/component, I think it's better to hook it into application level event listener instead. See http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/event/ContextRefreshedEvent.html

That way,you can make sure you all beans initialized, hence you can load `myListOfDates`, and then start the scheduler.

**Second**, like what I said in my comment, I would suggest you to uses existing 3rd-party library instead. I only ever uses Quartz in java, so I will ilustrate using Quartz.

**Third**, I guess you are storing `myListOfDates` in some kind of database (not memory), hence the ability of user to modify the scheduled dates. If you follow my suggestion in using 3rd-party library, Quartz have JobStore using JDBC See http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-09.html#TutorialLesson9-JDBCJobStore

Honestly I never uses that one, but I believe the library have mechanism to trigger the job based on what saved in the database. This might be what you are looking for.

Comment: I made it work thanks to the third tip : JobStore using JDBC.