# How to run spring boot application code to run only one time after spring bootrun completed

Tags: spring-boot

I have spring boot application. I have a below code. I want to execute this start method 10 minutes after bootrun is completed. This method should run only one time and that should be 10 minutes after successful bootrun. Can any one suggest how I can do this?

```
public class QueueController {
  
    //this method i want to run 10 minutes after successful bootun
    public String start() {
        //some code here to start some service
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37511097/scheduling-execute-tasks-only-one-time-in-spring-boot

Answer (score 0):

I don't sure you want to shutdown boot app programmatically but I can test with following sample code.

```
@EnableScheduling
@Component
public class Sample {

    private final ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public Sample(ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 10000) //run 10 sec after app starts
    void doSomething(){
        System.out.println("do something");

        applicationContext.close();

    }

}
```